# Regular expression of a string containing file path ending with [Number]x[Number].jpg (Thumbnail file)

Tags: c#, regex

i have a bunch of photos (Original + their different thumbnails). i want to delete all thumbnail files. so to do that i read all file path and stored in string array. now i want to check if the path is end with [Number]x[Number].jpg using regex. if yes delete that file.

Following are sample values of string array.

```
D:\Developer\Gallery\Maria-Menounos-at-Screen-Actors-Guild-Awards-2013--05-560x841.jpg
D:\Developer\Gallery\Maria-Menounos-at-Screen-Actors-Guild-Awards-2013--05.jpg
```

Below is my code.

```
string sDir = @"D:\Developer\Gallery\";
string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(sDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string file in Files)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(file, "[RegularExpression]"))
        File.Delete(file);
}
```

I am always poor at Regex :)

Please let me know the regular expression.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl `'x'` is the middle character of two number. basically it means dimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string file = @"D:\Developer\Gallery\Maria-Menounos-at-Screen-Actors-Guild-Awards-2013--05-560x841.jpg";

bool b = Regex.IsMatch(file, @"\d+x\d+\.jpg$");
```